# A $2$-Sylow subgroup of $A_5$ has five conjugates?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $A_5$ has exactly $5$ conjugates?

Recall $A_5$ is the group of even permutation of the first five positive integers.

Thanks

**Sketch:** We have $|A_5|=5\cdot 3\cdot 2^2$. Suppose $P$ is a $2$-Sylow of $A_5$. It suffices showing $$|N_{A_5}(P)|=12,$$ for in this case we would have: $$[N_{A_5}(P): P]=\frac{12}{4}=3$$ so that $$[A_5:N_{A_5}(P)]=\frac{[A_5:P]}{[N_{A_5}(P):P]}=\frac{15}{[N_{A_5}(P): P]}=\frac{15}{3}=5.$$
And, $[A_5: N_{A_5}(P)]$ is exactly the number of conjugates to $P$ in $A_5$.

Here $N_G(P):=\{g\in G: gPg^{-1}=P\}$ is the normalizer of $P$ in $G$.

Now I don't know how to show $|N_{A_5}(P)|=12$, however I conjecture $N_{A_5}(P)=A_4$.

Comment: Your conjecture offers a good and simple way for proving this. After all the unique Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_4$ is normal - it is that copy of Klein four. And it also happens to be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_5$.

Comment: A agree with your statements about the $2$-Sylows of $A_4$, but I still can't see how it will solve my problem, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It implies that $A_4\subseteq N_{A_5}(P)$, so $n=|N_{A_5}(P)|\ge12.$ Therefore the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $A_5$ is at most five. And also a factor of five, because five is a prime. After all $n$ is a factor of $60$ that is divisible by $12$, so either $n=12$ or $n=60$. Thus $60/n$ is either one or five. So if you can exhibit more than one Sylow $2$-subgroups of $A_5$, you will have exactly five of them. Can you do that? Hint: There are five natural copies of $A_4$ sitting as subgroups of $A_5$, each with there own Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about that =)

Answer (score 0):

$<(12)(34),(13)(24)>$ sits in $A_4$ when the latter is taken as the alternating subgroup of the permutation group on the symbols 1,2,3 and 4. Substitute 4 by 5 and you have $<(12)(35),(13)(25)>$ sitting in $A_4$ when the latter is taken as the alternating subgroup on the symbols 1,2,3 and 5. And both $A_4$s, or more precisely, both isomorphic copies of $A_4$ sit in $A_5$.