# Why are all pairs of order-12 subgroups of $A_5$ conjugate?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G:=A_5$. I want to know why every two subgroups of order $12$ of $G$ are conjugate in $G$?

My Work: $|G|=2^2 \times 3 \times 5$. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)$. Thus $P \cong C_2 \times C_2$. If $|H|=12$, then $H=P \rtimes Q \cong A_4$, where $|Q|=3$.
Now let $K$ be another subgroup of order $12$ of $G$. I cant understand why $H,K$ are conjugate in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroups of order $12$ in $A_5$ are given by the subgroups of even permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ having a single fixed point $k$, for $1\le k\le 5$. These are five subgroups, all isomorphic to $A_4$, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=GJwxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=subgroups+of+order+12+of+a5+are+isomorphic+to+A4&source=bl&ots=o_ppU-5cg5&sig=7upoFmtns61xkNg5WfSezrp8LkA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy_LTFjZzbAhVGUlAKHVAABA8Q6AEIUjAE#v=onepage&q=subgroups%20of%20order%2012%20of%20a5%20are%20isomorphic%20to%20A4&f=false). They are all conjugate, arising as normalizer of a $2$-sylow subgroup:

[A $2$-Sylow subgroup of $A_5$ has five conjugates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994760/a-2-sylow-subgroup-of-a-5-has-five-conjugates)

Comment: This can be seen directly, e.g. [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/A4_in_A5).